# search whether id consists of dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script below will loop through and generate 50 records. I have a dynamic value `RANKS = "8"`. How can I check if  8 is exists in id="rankN"?
The `value[RANKS]` is dynamic from 1-50

```js
var RANKS = "8";
var ranking;
for (var i = 0; i < rankingList.length; i++) {
  var a = 1;
  ranking = "<div > " +
    ("<div id=rank" + a + " class='RankCol'>" + rankingList[i].rankNo + "</div>") +
    ("<div>" + rankingList[i].username + "</div>") +
    ("<div>" + rankingList[i].winningAmt + "</div>") +
    ("<div> " + rankingList[i].uCoin + "</div>") +
    (" </div>");
};
```

Expected result:

1. A
2. A
3. B
4. B
5. C
6. B
7. A
8. **A**
9. B
10. G

so if my ranking is 8, the text will bold. IF the value is not within 50, then i will do another css. my main problem is how can i check whether the looped' ID contains the id number same as my RANKS(which is 8)

Comment: Since the generated IDs will go from 0 to `rankingList.length-1`, you know `id="rankN"` exists if `N < rankingList.length`.

Comment: Also note that `"id=rank" + a` will generate `id="rank8"` *not* `id="rank[8]"` (assuming you `a++` or use `i` instead of `a` - as it is, they'll all be `id="rank1"`!!)

Comment: Also, why do you think you need a "dynamic id"?  hint: you don't, there are better methods.  eg `"<div data-rank=" + i + ">"`

Comment: OK @ Jeremy Thille, I got what you mean how to do the checking of "N"

Comment: @freedomn-m, nope, i had update my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check in DOM, then simply `var exists = $('#rank8').length !== 0`.

If you want it to check inside loop:

```js
var ranks = {};

for (var i = 0; i < rankingList.length; i++) {
    newRank = 'rank' + i;

    if (typeof ranks[newRank] !== 'undefined') {
        // skip
        continue;
    } else {
        ranking = '<div id="' + newRank + '" ...';
    }

    ranks[newRank] = newRank;
}
```

Comment: hi @Justinas, cuz the  RANKS = "8"; is dyanmic, it could be any number. But i wanna check if the value is betwwen 0-50

Comment: *Now* you want to check if `RANKS` is between 0 and 50?   That's not clear from the question at all.  `if ((RANKS*1)>0 && (RANKS*1)<50)...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
rankingDiv.html(rankingList.map((rank,i) => `<div>
    <div id="rank${i+1)" class='RankCol'>${rank.rankNo}</div>
    <div>${rank.username}</div>
    <div>${rank.winningAmt}</div>
    <div>${rank.uCoin}</div>
    </div>`);
const $myRank = $(`#rank${RANKS}`);
if ($myRank.length===1) myRank.html(`<b>${$myRank.text()}</b>`)
```

Older sugggestion

```
$(\`#rank${RANKS}\`).length===1
```

Comment: Hi tried to do if statement for 1st options but give error

Comment: I think 1 options is what i looking for as i wan to check if the id=rank+myDynamicValue is exists

Comment: @JesscyTey I updated to jQuery - I had some DOM in there